# Changing from synchronous to asynchronus JMS message processing

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have a client that uses `JmsMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive()` to send a message and wait for a response.

```
messagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(myDest, myRequestObj,
                RequestObj.class);
```

On the server side, I have:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "myDest")
protected Message<MyResponseObj> handleRequest(final RequestObj requestObj) {
    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(newMyresponseObj)
            .setHeader(myHost)).build();
}
```

This works fine.

I'd like to do this asynchrously now. I still want the server to send back the response, and I still want the client to receive it, I just don't want the client to wait for it.

On the client side, I can set up a `@JMSListener` for the `MyResponseObj`. Would I just change my client side to call JmsMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(), rather than convertSendAndReceive? Would I need to do any changes on the server side `handleRequest()`?

What changes are required to set things up so the client will asynchronously receive the response?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `convertAndSend()` will send the message asynchronous. The client does not wait for an *answer*.

The server could send the *answer* to another queue and the client could listen to this.

You will need another *destination* for the *answer*-queue.

`@JmsListener(destination = "question")` on server-side and `@JmsListener(destination = "answer")` on client-side.